# Ubuntu 14.04 mouse not working but detected

Tags: 14.04, mouse, input-devices, xinput

I have a Razer Imperator mouse that used to work just fine until yesterday.

`lsusb`, `xinput` and `dmesg` all correctly list the mouse, but yet it doesn't work.

Can anyone give some tips on how to debug this?

Ubuntu 14.04 with everything up to date.

Comment: If you have any other mouses pluged in that might interfere with the current one you want to use but other than that I would reinstall the driver and check the batteries

Answer (score -1):

I've been having this problem since I got Ubuntu, My mouse would work for like 30 minutes after each time i started the computer and even though the hardware was visible in *lsusb* the mouse wouldn't move and the lights on my razer imperator wouldn't light up.  I fixed the issue by removing another USB mouse out of my computer, its been almost 10 hours now and the mouse works fine.  The other mouse probably interfered.